# SharePoint User Permisssion

Tags: permissions

We have sharepoint site running with many groups. Recently we face issue that some users have more rights than their group permissions. When we look into that group, that user was not mapped in that group. Here our question is how those users can access the application?

Site has sharepoint groups which are mapped to different AD groups.

To make my scenario understand, there are two sharepoint group A and B. These sharepoint groups are mapped to AD groups A and B. Now we have a user X who was not a member of both AD groups A and B but can access the application.

Comment: did you looked at site collection admin group if user is in there, there's no user can access a site without having access to it unless site allows anonymous access

Comment: Also confirm if user is not in "People and groups" and "Advanced permissions" @ site settings

Comment: You can also check permissions for an individual, which will give you the permissions the person has for the entire site ... this should give you where they are receiving their permissions from. You might get the info you need to correct it from there.